# Set default CardView for show initially

Tags: android, android-cardview

I have been working with android CardView lately and as far as I can see CardView will only display the first card first and then you can see the other cards after swiping down.

My question is: how can we set a Default `CardView` initially?.

**For example**

The display will show a card in particular position in the middle and you can swipe to see the other cards.

Comment: Put cardviews into a list, e.g, RecyclerView or ListView

Comment: Post your xml code, for your problem seams that your using `NestedScrollView` here if you use `RecyclerView` inside `NestedScrollView` it will scroll to recyclerview initial that's why you can see first `CardView`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to show a particular item at start, use `RecyclerView` and `scrollToPosition();`

```
RecyclerView rv=.......
rv.scrollToPosition(2); //position of card view
```

See [this](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.html#scrollToPosition(int)).

> it is a convenience method to scroll to a certain position.
>   RecyclerView does not implement scrolling logic, rather forwards the
>   call to `scrollToPosition(int)`

And use `cardview` as elements for your needs.